# Shorten/reduce the conditions/parameters when all parameters(after the where clause) come from one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below code is working perfectly, But I feel it is too long,
I want to transfare the value "1" in the field "MealNo" before delete it's record to the row that has the field MealNo=2

The below code do the job, but I see it very long, is there are any way to shorten it? especialy after the "where"

```
 if ((SELECT MealNo FROM [Temp_Food_TBL] WHERE [AutoNo] = @AutoNo) = 1)
    BEGIN 
        Update [Temp_Food_TBL]
        SET
         MealNo = 1
         Where
         MealNo = 2
         AND
         PersonID = (SELECT PersonID FROM [Temp_Food_TBL] WHERE [AutoNo] = @AutoNo)
         AND
         MealTime = (SELECT MealTime FROM [Temp_Food_TBL] WHERE [AutoNo] = @AutoNo)
         AND
         MealDate = (SELECT MealDate FROM [Temp_Food_TBL] WHERE [AutoNo] = @AutoNo)  
    END

 DELETE FROM [Temp_Food_TBL]
   WHERE 
 [AutoNo] = @AutoNo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a self-join instead of using the `WHERE` statements.

```
if ((SELECT MealNo FROM [Temp_Food_TBL] WHERE [AutoNo] = @AutoNo) = 1)
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE t1
        SET t1.MealNo = 1
        FROM [Temp_Food_TBL] AS t1
        INNER JOIN [Temp_Food_TBL] AS t2
          ON t1.PersonID = t2.PersonID
            AND t1.MealTime = t2.MealTime
            AND t1.MealDate = t2.MealDate
            AND t1.MealNo = 2 
        WHERE t2.AutoNo = @AutoNo 
    END 

   DELETE FROM [Temp_Food_TBL]
   WHERE [AutoNo] = @AutoNo
```

That isn't really radically shorter. But with several criteria for finding the matching row, I'm not sure that you can shorten it all that much.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH DATA AS
(
      SELECT
            Temp_Food_TBL.*
      FROM
            Temp_Food_TBL
            INNER JOIN Temp_Food_TBL AS Match
                  ON Temp_Food_TBL.PersonID = Match.PersonID
                  AND Temp_Food_TBL.MealTime = Match.MealTime
                  AND Temp_Food_TBL.MealDate = Match.MealDate
                  AND Match.AutoNo = @AutoNo
                  AND Match.MealNo = 1
)
UPDATE DATA SET MealNo = 2

DELETE FROM Temp_Food_TBL WHERE AutoNo = @AutoNo
```